# Detect Anomaly Pattern

Tags: clustering

I have a datasets which contains anomaly data shaped like crossed. Please advise how can I filter these pattern? I have tried DBscan but it can't detect the cross pattern. Please advise Thanks

[image]

Comment: Maybe try to look for spikes in x and y projections.

Comment: Hi @Antonina, could you share some link to the algoritm?

Comment: Some peak or outlier detection method. It depends on the x and y projections series. There are a lot of them, from simple https://www.baeldung.com/cs/signal-peak-detection  to more complex http://geoanalytics.net/and/papers/iv10.pdf (it is only example of some methods).